# Scala Typeclass for methods with parameters

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have tried to add methods like "multiply by a scalar" to `Array[T]` via a typeclass, to mimic numpy functionality. I have looked at [an example](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html), which works and adds a "show" method with no parameters to `Array[T]`. However, in my case, I find that I am unable to add methods with parameters, e.g. `array.*(2.0)`.

Using Scala 2.12.6.

How can I make this code work?

```
package numpy

trait BehaveLikeNumpy[T] {
  def *(a: Array[T], x: T): Array[T]
}

object BehaveLikeNumpyInstances {

  def apply[T](implicit bln: BehaveLikeNumpy[T]): BehaveLikeNumpy[T] = bln

  object ops {
    def *[T: BehaveLikeNumpy](a: Array[T], x: T): Array[T] = BehaveLikeNumpyInstances[T].*(a, x)

    implicit class BehaveLikeNumpyOps[T: BehaveLikeNumpy](a: Array[T]) {
      def *(x: T) = BehaveLikeNumpyInstances[T].*(a, x)
    }
  }

  implicit val arrayTimes_Double = (a: Array[Double], x: Double) => a.map(y => y * x)
}

package some.pkg
import numpy.BehaveLikeNumpyInstances
import numpy.BehaveLikeNumpyInstances.ops._

val aaa: Array[Double] = (0 until 5).toArray.map(_.toDouble)
aaa.show // Works. See https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html
val s1 = aaa.*(2.0)// Error: value * is not a member of Array[Double]
val s2 = aaa * 2.0 // Error: value * is not a member of Array[Double]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you lost type (for transformation of lambda to SAM trait)

```
implicit val arrayTimes_Double: BehaveLikeNumpy[Double] = 
  (a: Array[Double], x: Double) => a.map(y => y * x)
```

secondly you lost underscore

```
import numpy.BehaveLikeNumpyInstances._
```

Comment: With your proposed changes I get the same errors, plus: `type mismatch; found: (Array[Double], Double) => Array[Double]; required: numpy.BehaveLikeNumpy[Double]`

Comment: What is your Scala? This works in 2.12. In 2.11 you should write `arrayTimes_Double: BehaveLikeNumpy[Double] = new BehaveLikeNumpy[Double]...` manually instead of the lambda.

Comment: Scala 2.12.6. Added it to the post (was not there initially).

Comment: OK - your code works, and I figured out what the issue is with my code (in addition to what you said): I defined multiplication *and also addition*. I have a "+" method everywhere there is a "\*" method in this example. If I remove the "+" methods, it all works. If I add the "+" methods, it stops compiling. The code for "+" is trivially derived from "\*" - so the issue must be that now there is a confusion as to which implicit to use. Do I need to replicate all the code for each operation I want to add, i.e. have a whole new set of trait, object, ops, etc?

Comment: No, you can just add `def +` to `trait BehaveLikeNumpy`, `object ops` and `implicit class BehaveLikeNumpyOps`, manually define `implicit val arrayTimes_Double` with `new` without lambda (since `BehaveLikeNumpy` is no longer a SAM trait) and with the same two imports both `+` and `*` should work.

Comment: Don't define two lambdas like `implicit val arrayTimes_Double`.